# Proximal operator of the difference of negative entropy and squared norm

Tags: convex-optimization, proximal-operators

Let $\lambda >0$. I am looking for an analytic expression of
\begin{equation}
\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda\psi} (x),
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{prox}$ denotes the proximal operator, and $\psi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined for every $x=(x_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}\in \mathbb{R}^n$ by
\begin{equation}
\psi(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ln (x_i) - \frac{x_i^2}{2} & \text{if } x\in \mathcal{U}, \\+\infty & \text{otherwise}, \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
where $\mathcal{U}$ is the simplex of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In the case $\lambda=1$, it can be shown (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.07526.pdf Example 2.23 for instance) that $\mathrm{prox}_{\psi}$ is the **softmax operator**. In the case $\lambda\neq 1$, I am unable to reproduce a similar proof.

Any help is welcomed !

Comment: You should try to write $prox_{\lambda \psi}$ in terms of $prox_\psi$.